# Normal map bake result for humanoid mesh projects arms on torso

Tags: rendering, texturing, baking, normal-map

I'm trying to create a normal map of my high-resolution sculpt to my low-resolution mesh, but I'm getting weird results.

As the scene is setup, the high-res and low-poly meshes are overlapping each other, almost perfectly as can be seen below. But when I bake the normal map, I get weird results. Below, you can see the arms being projected onto the torso of the character, some distortion also occurs on the chin.

How can I resolve this?

[image: Problematic normal map bake]

Comment: In the bake settings try to change the bias below 1

Comment: Hey @Denis ! I tried what you recommended and it [worked](http://imgur.com/a/h9MmF)! There are still some weird deformations but I think I can work them out. If you can convert your comment into an answer, I can reward you that sweet, sweet rep! Thanks! If you can also provide some insight into what the Distance and Bias actually means for the bake, that would be greatly appreciated! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bias in Baking settings means how far away (in blender units) from the surface the geometry will be captured onto the baked texture.

If the value is too high that may cause capturing additional information that is perpendicular to the surface within the set Bias.

To fix that problem you can zoom into the model and use the grid to estimate the distance to avoid capturing unwanted detais.